# Как добавить мультиязычность ACF PRO + WPML?

Tags: wordpress

делаю сайт на WP. В основном готовые HTML вертски интегрирую с Wordpress через кастомные поля ACF PRO. Требуется сделать мультиязычность с помощью WPML. Помню с Polylang это было очень легко , просто добавлял значения для разных языков для полей. И в зависимости от языка он подгружал нужные данные. Но как быть с WPML ( поменять не могу и надо лишь его использовать !! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте плагин ACFML (ACF Multilingual), который идёт в составе WPML. Скачать его можно в личном кабинете на сайте wpml.org.

Comment: Спасибо, а подскажите пожалуйста стандартным WPML никак нельзя?

Comment: А что такое "стандартный"? Если купленный - то у вас есть доступ в личный кабинет. Если ворованный плагин, то лучше вообще о нём вопросы не задавать.

Comment: Нет , куплен конечно, просто мы на существующий сайт уже добавили новые страницы. И старые программисты почему то твердят что можно без ACFML переводить кастомные поля.

Comment: Пусть твердят что угодно. Обратитесь в поддержку WPML - там вам скажут то же самое.